# setInterval exits after first iteration. Please help me rectify this snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me rectify the issue related to the `setInterval`? I'm fairly new to JavaScript, I'm not sure what's wrong here. I have this block in my page:

```
GlobalTicker.prototype.TickElements = function () {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.initializeElement.apply(this) , 1000);
};
GlobalTicker.prototype.initializeElement = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tickerElements.length; i++) {
        var existingRun = this.tickerElements[i].secs;
        var elementId = $('#' + this.tickerElements[i].id + ' .comment-editor').find('.ticker');
        existingRun -= 1;
        $(elementId).text(existingRun);
        if (existingRun === 0) {
            $(elementId).remove();
            this.tickerElements.splice(i, 1);
            if (this.tickerElements.length == 0) clearInterval(this.tickerElements.timer);
        }
    }
};
```

Then somewhere in the code, I have this call in a function

```
var objTicker = new GlobalTicker();
CommentManagement.prototype.createComment = function (domObject) {
    objTicker.TickElements();
};
```

This function call actually invokes the `setInterval` function and runs the first iteration and jumps to the `initialiseComment();` but once this block is executed, on the next interval, instead of executing the `initialiseComment();` again, it jumps back to my function call `CreateComment();`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval()` requires a function reference.  You were calling the function itself and passing the return result from executing the function (which was `undefined`) to `setInterval()`.  Since that return value is not a function, there was no callback function for `setInterval()` to call.  Thus, your method was executed once when you first called it, but couldn't be called by the interval.

To fix it, you should change from this:

```
this.timer = setInterval(this.initializeElement.apply(this) , 1000);
```

to this:

```
var self = this;
this.timer = setInterval(function() {self.initializeElement()}, 1000);
```

Note, the value of `this` will also be different in the `setInterval()` callback than the value you want so the one you want is saved here in `self` so it can be referenced from that.  There's also no need to use `.apply()` in this case because calling a method on an object will automatically set the `this` pointer as needed.

Comment: Another option instead of the anonymous function is jQuery's [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function. Example: `setInterval($.proxy(this.initializeElement, this), 1000);`. The function returns a new function which calls the given function with the given object as context.

Comment: @tcovo - `.bind()` in modern browsers will also do the same thing, but I prefer the slightly more verbose method that makes it more obvious (to me) what is happening.